# How do I add Enhanced Security Login to my website

Tags: asp.net, security, web, authentication

I am developing an ASP.NET website and wanted to add another layer of protection to my users.

When they login from a new machine then they would need to setup that new machine with my website after answering 3 security questions.

How can I do this?

Cookies? Is there any other way?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no point in requiring 3 security questions as opposed to one.  If you want to be secure, use a hardware token, such as a SecurID or a smart card.

Comment: That would mean that I would need to distribute these hardware pieces to my end users...looking for a more cost effective solution - Thanks though

Comment: Security isn't cheap.  Slapping on two more of the same thing will add lots of frustration and a _tiny_ bit of security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When they login from a new machine

You want to track users who's machines are *new to your website*. The only possible way you can achieve this reliably is through using cookies.  If they haven't been to your site before, then they won't have passed your cookie along during the request.

Therefore if the user is missing your cookie when they first request the page (assuming this is after log on?), then get them to answer the questions. Once the questions have been passed successfully, mark this in your database with a key and check future requests for a cookie containing this key.

Comment: so if the user clears his cookies then I lose the machine info, right?

Comment: if the user clears his cookies he will look like a new computer again, and they'll have to answer the questions.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to track known IP addresses.  You could force the user to answer the questions if the request is from an unknown IP.

Comment: True, but considering that ISPs can change your IP's on you, wouldnt that make the user answer these questions when not needed?

Comment: I agree this just isn't reliable

Comment: Agreed, the cookie is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use a persistent cookie.  If the persistent cookie value doesn't match something you have stored on your database, make them answer the questions, and then set a persistent cookie value.